# Inconsistent margins with non-standard enumeration

Tags: beamer, enumerate

In Latex Beamer, when I have an enumeration with custom labels, using e.g. `\begin{enumerate}[a]` for "a... b... c..." or `\begin{enumerate}[i]` for "i... ii... iii..." instead of "1. ... 2. ... 3. ...", then the left margin seems to be smaller and thus inconsistent with the other slides.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item normal margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[i]
        \item smaller margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[a]
        \item much smaller margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[a] normal margin, but manual labels
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When I use `item[a]`, `item[b]` etc., then the margins are correct, but for obvious reasons this is not perfect, either. Is there any way to fix this?

---

Update: The problems seems not to be specific to the `beamer` class, but to the `enumerate` package (that is used by or copied from in `beamer`) as the same behaviour occurs with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

Still, I am mainly interested in a solution that works well with `beamer`.

Comment: Are you using `enumitem` package with its `shortlabels` optiontogether with `babel`?

Comment: Beamer and enumitem are not supposed to work together. But there are other solutions for changing the labels. Did you try anything else?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer @ TeXnician `enumitem` is not necessary to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm using just the `beamer` class and regular Latex `enumerate`. Added a full minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @TeXnician How comes? After all it comes with styled enumeration numbers and stuff. Also, the `[a]` and `[i]` options seem to be specific to `beamer` (or some package beamer uses), as they do not work in a plain `article` style. I tried only what's shown in the example.

Comment: @tobias_k The `[a]` syntax for enumerations is part of the `enumerate` package which is loaded by `beamer`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Beamer does not load the `enumerate` package, it "partly copied from enumerate.sty", see `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` l. 175 ff

Comment: @samcarter I was just reading the documentation: "*you do not need to include the enumerate package, this is done automatically*" (p.112). :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I `grep`ed the beamer folder for all `\usepackage`, `\Requirepackage` and `{enumerate}` and could not find anything loading the `enumerate` package. Ok, theoretically it could be loaded by some other package, but I think the docu is a bit misleading :)

Comment: @samcarter look in the log file from the test file in the question, you will see that `enumerate.sty` is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can just comment out the lines that re-set the indentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@@@enum@[#1]{% partly copied from enumerate.sty
  \@enLab{}\let\@enThe\@enQmark
  \@enloop#1\@enum@
  \ifx\@enThe\@enQmark\@warning{The counter will not be printed.%
    ^^J\space\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces The label is: \the\@enLab}\fi
  \def\insertenumlabel{\the\@enLab}
  \def\beamer@enumtempl{enumerate mini template}%
   \expandafter\let\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname\@enThe
%  \csname c@\@enumctr\endcsname7
%  \expandafter\settowidth
%            \csname leftmargin\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
%            {\the\@enLab\hspace{\labelsep}}%
  \beamer@enum@}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item normal margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[i]
        \item smaller margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[a]
        \item much smaller margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[a] normal margin, but manual labels
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now the items are no longer "a, b, ..." and "i, ii, ..." but just numbers again, as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: @tobias_k oops:-) a minor detail. I'll delete this answer and put it back in a bit once it works.

Comment: @tobias_k sorry I had one too many `%` in the first answer, try now.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. (I figured it was something as simple as a misplaced `%`, but to be honest, I'm still having troubles wrapping my head around that `\def`)

Answer (score 4):

To get the same margins as if using `\item[a]` you could simply define your own enumerate item `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\alph{enumi}}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item normal margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[i]
        \item smaller margin
    \end{enumerate}
    {
    \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\alph{enumi}}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item much smaller margin
    \end{enumerate}
    }
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[a] normal margin, but manual labels
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it defeats the simplicity of the `[a.]` syntax which `beamer` is supposed to support.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am looking forward to learn why `[a.]` changes the margin :)

Comment: It seems that this is how the `enumerate` package works. (Same effect even with `article` class and `enumerate` loaded.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Just had a look around the site and there are tons of questions about why the alphabetic enumeration is not indented. However most answers just recommended using `enumitem` instead, so not applicable to beamer :(

Comment: @samcarter because that's how I defined it:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, it's not a bug but a feature?

Comment: @tobias_k https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38541073#38541073

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I did not know this is being discussed in chat. So by default, the width of the label is determined by how wide the 7th label would be? Explains why the indent for "a" was even less than for "i", since "vii" is wider than "g".

Comment: @tobias_k yes I (some time last millennium) just wanted to make sure there was room for the label so I picked the widest (small) roman number and based the width on that.

Answer (score 1):

Another rather hacky way to solve/circumvent the problem I found is to insert padding directly into the `[a.]` or `[i.]` parameter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item normal margin
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[~~a.]
        \item normal margin (almost)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course, this does not align the different enumerations perfectly, and could also depend on the font being used. I would probably not use this in a printed document, but for some slides it might be good enough. The same also works (with somewhat more precision) with e.g. `[\hspace{8pt}a.]`.